# Configure NodeJs on Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I installed the NodeJS plugin 1.3.7 on an installation of Jenkins 2.235.2. After restarting Jenkins I see the NodeJS options on job configuration screens, but there is nothing on the Jenkins configuration screen that makes any mention of Node, so I am not able to add any installations for the jobs to use. I've found several sources that say that clicking **Check now** on the **Advanced** tab of the Plugin Manager screen will solve this, but that has had no effect. Can anyone suggest what else I might try to be able to add Node installations, or explain what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to **Manage Jenkins >> Global tool configuration**

and configure node there according to you

[image]

and in your jenkinsfile use

```
tools {
  nodejs "nodejs-2.x"
}
```